# Exhaustive List of Tactics In Dafny?

Tags: dafny

I am new Dafny and verification. I understand that when the dafny prover fails to verify a program, the user has to annotate the program with guidance/hints for the verifier. However, I am not able to anticipate when and where the dafny verifier will fail. Whereas something like Coq provides an exhaustive list of tactics that can be used in the proof.

For example: In this [example (Section 4)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.04481.pdf), by simply looking at the pen and paper version of the lemma "For all n >= 1, f(n) = 2^{3n} - 3^{n} is divisible by 5." and its proof, I am not able to anticipate when and where the dafny verifier will need hints.

Is there a guide on scenarios when dafny would need hints/guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking as a relatively experienced Dafny user, I wouldn't say I'm always able to perfectly predict when Dafny will need help. I just let the verifier tell me.

Because of this need for frequent feedback from the verifier, it is borderline-required that you use an editor that can run the verifier for you in the background and give you nice red squiggles (vscode and emacs both have extensions that support this out of the box).

As for an exhaustive list of tactics, I hear where your coming from, but such a list does not really exist for Dafny. The underlying solver either gets it, or it doesn't, and there is an art in figuring out what kinds of things help it or not. Unlike in interactive tools such as Coq, there is nothing you can do to "see" what the problem is directly.

### How to "see" what you can't see

That said, you can learn how to efficiently debug verification problems by using a simple binary-search-like technique. For example, if an ensures clause is failing, I might copy-paste it as an assert in the bottom of the method. Then if that assert is made up of two things `&&`-ed together, I might assert each of them separately. Then if one of the conjuncts uses a predicate definition, I might manually copy-paste and inline that predicate and do further manual simplifications, to narrow down which part is failing.

Now that you've narrowed down the problem to a single line/definition with no further manual expansion or simplification possible, you need an annotation.

### What kinds of annotations you can add

Off the top of my head, I would distinguish two kinds of "helping" the verifier that are important in practice.

- **Interface annotations**, which includes pre/postconditions, modifies clauses, *and loop invariants*. These annotations affect the logical formulas that Dafny asks the underlying solver to prove. By adjusting these annotations, you can turn an unprovable formula into a provable one.
- **Local annotations**, often in the form of assert statements. A lot of the interesting things that Dafny can reason about involve quantifiers (`forall`/`exists`). Even if your program doesn't use any quantifiers explicitly, they are lurking in the internals of Dafny's basic data structures, such as sequences, sets, and maps. Unfortunately, reasoning about quantifiers in general is undecidable, which means the underlying solver is based on heuristics that work a lot of the time, but not all the time. In those cases, mentioning other true facts via assert statements can "trigger" the solver to reason differently, allowing it to prove the formula.

These two annotations differ in that Interface annotations change the logical content of the verification problem, whereas Local annotations leave the basic verification problem the same while just mentioning some additional helpful facts.

### Conclusion

Dafny has a sort of strangely shaped learning curve. At the beginning everything is great and feels really natural and wonderful. Then at some point, you start running into verification errors that don't make sense to you. Your first response is to poke at the code sort of randomly until these errors go away. Over time, you get a better sense for what kinds of things help and don't help Dafny.

Learning (or teaching!) these strategies is hard. If you can, I suggest finding an expert you can talk to frequently as you work with Dafny. In the absence of any local experts, you can keep posting here, or you might try the [gitter chat](https://gitter.im/dafny-lang/community). (I'm not a big fan of gitter myself, but others in the community use it.)

Finally, I suggest reading (the quite possibly overwhelming amount of) reference material on Dafny. I recommend starting with the [FAQ](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ) and the [tutorial](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/guide). Then you can take a look at the [Dafny power user](http://leino.science/dafny-power-user/) and the [reference manual](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/raw/master/docs/DafnyRef/out/DafnyRef.pdf). You might also find this [Systems Software Verification Summer Camp 2020](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Emanosk/summer-school-2020.html) useful. It teaches the binary search technique (but only as a side note -- there are about 15 hours of video lectures in total, mostly about verifying models of distributed systems).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Especially for sharing the distributed systems verification summer camp lectures.